# Where do I override EDITOR to gvim when in X?

Tags: ssh, vim, gvim

When I connect to a machine remotely using `ssh`, without `-X`, I'd like for `less`'s <kbd>v</kbd> and `hg commit` to open `vim`.  I know I can do this with `export EDITOR=vim`.  However, if I login locally, or via `ssh` with `-X`, I'd like gvim to open in those cases.  Can this be accomplished by calling `export EDITOR=gvim` in the right initialization file?  If so, which one and how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you want to set your editor in your local profile (e.g. `~/.bash_profile` for bash, `~/.zprofile` for zsh or the common `~/.profile`). This file is executed every time that you login.

An easy way to switch between a graphical and non-graphical editor is to check if the `DISPLAY` environment variable is set when exporting the `EDITOR` environment:

```
export EDITOR="$(if [[ -n "$DISPLAY" ]]; then echo 'gvim'; else echo 'vim'; fi)"
```

(Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/environment_variables#Examples)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is create a small shell script and place it in `~/bin`, and set your EDITOR variable to point to it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ]
then
    vim "$@"
else
    gvim "$@"
fi
```